# Oscillation on PWM output microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, oscillation

I was trying to create a 20 kHz PWM signal with a PIC16F684 microcontroller.
I noticed some oscillation on the single when I hook my scope on the PWM output of de microcontroller (see image below).

This oscillation only appears when I use a 20 MHz crystal instead of the internal oscillator of the microcontroller. The internal oscillater operates at 8 MHz.

From where is this oscillation coming and what can be done to avoid it?

Many thanks in advance.

**ADDED:**
I have attached a schematic, I am measuring between the ground and pin 5.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What oscillation do you refer to?

Comment: The sine wave at the bottom.

Comment: Then we need a circuit diagram to see what you have done.

Comment: Something has gone really wrong, the micro is totem-pole output, the low-level signal should be flat if you have your ground clip of your probe connected to your circuit ground.

Comment: Yes, the groundclip is connected to the ground signal. But I have absolutely no idea what went wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka: I have added a circuit diagram.

Comment: Your scope probe ground wire needs to be at a zero volt node closest to your measurement point.

Comment: They are not more than 2 cm separated form each other. I used another oscilloscope en there is oscillation at the bottom. Any idea why one scope sees this sine wave and the other one doesn't?

Comment: That 60 kHz sine is unrelated in frequency to your PWM - it is being generated elsewhere (perhaps in the 'scopes switcher power supply?). Check that 'scope's ground path from probe right back to AC wall outlet "gnd" pin.

Comment: I removed C8 and C9 from the diagram above and then the sine wave is gone. I it possible that some kind of oscillation frequency was reached with a combinetion of these cermamic capacitors and the input impedance of the scope?

Comment: probably just capacitance in the wires, leads, scope, etc...